# Reading Strings using retrofit http client

Tags: jackson, retrofit2

I have a test http server which returns some jackson annotated classes and one method returns raw string. 
Jackson annotated classes are serialized well into json strings but string returned by getUserName() is not json serialized. 
Retrofit client I am using expects the string returned by getUserName() method to be json serialized and throws an exception during deserialization. 
Is there some annotation I can use to tell retrofit to not deserialize the string returned by this method.

===== Test Http Server =====

```
@Path("v1/testserver")
public class TestServer {

    @GET
    @Path("username")
    public String getUserName() {
        return "Dummy user name";
    }

    .........
}
```

===== Test Http Client using Retrofit =====

```
public interface RetrofitTestService {
    @GET("username")
    Call<String> getUserName();
}

public class TestClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://localhost:8080/v1/testserver/")
            .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

        RetrofitTestService service = retrofit.create(RetrofitTestService.class);

        Call<String> userName = service.getUserName();
        try {
            System.out.printf("UserName: " + userName.execute().body());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried adding .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create()) to Retrofit as well, but that didn't help either.

Comment: Found more discussion here: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1151

Answer (score 2):

Using .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create()) did help. 
I was using wrong version of converter-scalars artifact before.